# How to stop my machine asking for multiple passwords when I log in?

Tags: macos, password, keychain

Ever since I changed my user account password, every time I log in to my machine I have to enter multiple passwords. First, I enter the new account password to actually log in. Once I'm at my desktop I get prompted to enter a few other passwords too. Namely the following:

[image: Messages Agent]
[image: Chrome]
[image]

My old password is required to successfully dismiss all of the above pop-ups. Is there some way of updating anything in my keychain that still uses the old password, to use the new password?

Any ideas what could have caused this? I can only imagine that the intended behaviour is for this update to happen automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you change your account's password using your Mac OS X Install disc (or if your network-based account password is changed due to a network admin forcing a password change), your default keychain password (which uses the same initial password as your user account) does not change.

[Support Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1631) helps:

If you want your default keychain to be unlocked automatically when you log in, synchronize your Keychain Access and account login passwords by doing this:

1. Open `Keychain Access` (you can get to it by choosing Utilities from the Go menu in the Finder).
2. From the `Edit menu`, choose `Change Password for Keychain "login."`
3. Type the former password of the account that you are currently logged in to, then click OK.
4. If you entered the correct password, a new window appears; enter the original password again in the `Current Password` field.
5. In the `New Password` field, type the password that matches your current account password.
6. Re-enter the newer password in the `Verify` field, then click OK.

**If you don't remember your original (former) account password**

If you don't remember your original password, you'll need to delete the keychain. Deleting a keychain also deletes all the password data saved in that keychain.

1. In `Keychain Access.app`, choose `Preferences` from the Keychain Access menu.
2. If available, click the `Reset My Default Keychain` button. This will remove the login keychain and create a new one with the password provided.
3. If `Reset My Default Keychain` is not available, choose `Keychain List` from the Edit menu.
4. Delete the "login" keychain.

The next time you log in to the account, you can save your current password in a keychain.

**If the above fails or doesn't fit:**

1. Open `Keychain Access.app`
2. Select the `"login" keychain` from the keychains list
3. Click the lock at the top to lock the `"login" keychain`
4. Click the lock again to unlock the login
5. After entering your `"login" keychain` password you should be presented with a dialog
6. Clicking the reset button will re-sync your `"login" keychain` password with the iCloud keychain password.

Info: [Discussions Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23467048#23467048)

**If everything from the above fails for whatever reason the last resort you can do is the following:**

1. Quit all running Applications
2. In Finder `Select Go > Go to folder` (⇧⌘G)
3. In the window that appears, type the following: `~/Library/Keychains/`
4. Click OK.
5. Look for a folder with a random name similar to this "A8F5E7B8-CEC1-4479-A7DF-F23CB076C8B8". Note: Each folder has a unique number.
6. Move this folder to the Trash.
7. Immediately choose `Apple Menu () > Restart…` to restart your Mac.

Info: Support Apple

Comment: If I reset my keychain will it affect my private keys/certificates for iOS development?

Comment: yes, you will loose all your passwords and certificates reseting your personal 'login' keychain

Comment: I had this problem on El Capitan, and my solution was to turn off FileVault under System Preferences > Security and Privacy. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231340/os-x-is-repeatedly-asking-for-login-keychain-password/231886#231886