# Stop "...wants to use keychain" password prompts

Tags: macos, keychain

Because of Xcode bug I had to reset my default keychain, and since then I'm getting annoying messages like this:

[image]
[image]

Here is what does not work:

- unlock keychains
- reset default keychain
- change keychains password
- remove `~/Library/Keychains`.

It keeps popping once in 15-30 min, sometimes multiple times in a row.

Note that there are no "fix keychain" or "keychain aid" anymore in macOS Sierra Keychain Access app.

Here are [two](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148433/how-to-stop-my-machine-asking-for-multiple-passwords-when-i-log-in) [old](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124591/osx-is-repeatedly-asking-for-login-keychain-password) questions with outdated answers.

I would prefer not to create access exceptions for all items, and it's not allowed for iCloud keychain ("Access for this item cannot be edited").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple support suggested to create new macOS user account; though this bug seems to be fixed by recent updates.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure this with the Keychain Access application that you can find in Application/Utilities.

- Select the password or the key in the main list and double click on it.
- Click on the Access Control tab then allow access to all applications or add a specific application in the list by clicking the plus sign at the bottom right.

Comment: Do you suggest to add safari to access all local keys? Also how do I find which key AddressBookSourceSync tries to access?

Comment: It depends on the trade off you want to make between usability and security but I think you can consider Safari as "safe" and give it access to your local keys. About AddressBookSourceSync, you already know that it need the keychain "iCloud", you can probably deduce the item from the context.

Comment: Actually, you can't edit access for iCloud items.

Answer (score 6):

Your Mac keeps asking for the login keychain password and this means 
The password of your macOS user account might not match the password of your login keychain.

It might also tell you that the system was unable to unlock your login keychain. That's because your login keychain is still using another password.

If you don't know your this password, the solution is to create a new login keychain or reset to default.

- Open Keychain Access, which is in the Utilities folder within the Applications folder.or **Launchpad > Utilities > Keychain Access**
- From the Keychain Access menu, choose Preferences.
- Click General, then click Reset My Default Keychain.
- Add your account login password.
- Quit Keychain Access then Restart your computer.

> From [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609)
>
> If you know your old password, use that password to update your existing login keychain:
>
> - Open the Keychain Access app, which is in the the Utilities folder of your Applications folder. or **Launchpad > Utilities > Keychain Access**
> - From the Edit menu, choose “Change Password for Keychain 'login.'”
> - Enter the old password of your user account in the Current Password field. This is the password you were using before the password was reset.
> - Enter the new password of your user account in the New Password field. This is the password you're now using to log in to your Mac. Enter the same password in the Verify field.
> - Click OK when done, then quit Keychain Access.

Comment: I tried to reset/recreate default keychain, and tried to change password. It did not help. Also I can't change password for iCloud keychain.

Comment: did you create new Keychain ?

Comment: You should cite your references according to this standard : http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: Please share any reference and I will add it too

Comment: Yes, I tried to create new keychain and tried to remove ~/Library/Keychain completely (and clear corresponding plist).

Comment: Try to sign-out from iCloud **System Preferences> iCloud** and reset to default and then reconnect to iCloud

Comment: I don't want to say it but you may need to reset the whole OS after backup your data

Comment: How to make MacOS stop asking for password? just give it the password. . . . . .

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you have set up your login key-chain to auto-lock after several minutes of inactivity. This can be configured - although the UI for that is hidden, and not in the menu of **KeyChain Access** app

Open your **KeyChain Access** application, then select the login keychain. Then right-click (contextual-menu click) the small icon of the login keychain.

[image]

and choose "Change Settings for Kechain "login"

There you can set it to NOT lock itself automatically, or only do so after longer period of inactivity, or only auto-lock when mac goes to sleep (which in my opinion makes more sense)

Answer (score -3):

For signing in to the App Store use the login keychain password.

Comment: Entering the password doesn't work to stop the dialogs from appearing in the future, that's the premise of the question.