# Prevent services from prompting for imported keychain password on login

Tags: keychain, login

I have a new Macbook, I exported my old Keychain and added it to my new account. I have a couple of these keychains that I've brought with me to each new machine over the years.

**When I login, it asks me several times for the password to these keychains, how do I prevent this?**

Note these keychains are not my login keychain.

[image: ss]

[image: kcs]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148433/how-to-stop-my-machine-asking-for-multiple-passwords-when-i-log-in

Comment: thanks, saw that but it referred to the login keychain

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like this is possible. At least according to this blog post.

*Reference: [Mac and iOS Keychain Tutorial: How Apple’s iCloud Keychain Works](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/mac-and-ios-keychain-tutorial-how-apples-icloud-keychain-works/)*

> Note that while your login keychain is the default, it is unlocked as
>   soon as you log into your Mac. You can increase security by creating a
>   non-login keychain — all this requires is an additional password when
>   you start up or log into your Mac

I think what you'd need to do here is likely import the copied keychain file's content to the main keychain file if that's the behavior that you want.

Comment: Can I just select all and move, or since these keychains used to be "login" on other machines, are there items I should avoid bringing across to avoid conflicts?